# WCF Rest Service Error : httpsGetEnabled = false and still shows the error to configure its value

Tags: wcf, rest, binding, https, web-config

I have a wcf service and following is the error i receive:

The HttpsGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpsGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no https base address.  Either supply an https base address or set HttpsGetUrl to an absolute address.

My web.config settings is as below :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TBServiceProvider" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="ITBServiceProvider" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://www.xyz.com:8000"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

The above settings work perfectly fine on localhost, but when it is uploaded to the server, the above mentioned error occurs. Please let me know what can be done to make the service work on hosting server.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you host your service ? IIS or windows service ?

Comment: The service is placed on a shared hosting server, over IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, base address prefix is not needed. You can delete this parameter.

Then you should replace httpsGetEnabled by httpGetEnabled. You don't need to specify httpsGetEnabled, if you don't expose your service on TLS.

Finally, can you add a screenshot of your service displayed in Internet Explorer on your server, and on a remote computer.

Comment: Not able to access the internet as I cannot login as remote server. But one more issue was created. Above mentioned solution did work. I am also placing here the least required things I placed to make the service working on a hosting server.

Comment: What are the authentication levels allowed in IIS ? If you don't need security, Anonymous Authnetication must be set to enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Update in web.config file

```
 <system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="TBSERVICe">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="Web"
              contract="ITBSERVICE" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Addition in TBSERVICE.svc file

```
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```

These mentioned settings worked well for hosting webservice on server.
My issue was also regarding the files are not updated when any changes are made on them, ie project files like .svc and web.config were still accepted from some temporary storage by hosting server. Would always prefer to place on atleast 2 servers then.

Thanks